# Android: unable to create Media Player (using pls URL)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to create an app that plays an internet radio stream from a .pls file. I know that the Android Media Player can't read .pls files, so I read it beforehand and obtained the URL that is stored in the .pls file. That's what's in the `R.String.audio_stream` variable I pass to setDataSource(). However, when I run my code on the simulator, it fails when I try to start the media player. LogCat returns the error message, "Unable to create media player." Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button mStartButton;
    private Button mStopButton;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mStartButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isPlaying){
                    //do nothing
                }else{
                    isPlaying = true;
                    try{
                        mp.setDataSource(getString(R.string.audio_stream));
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed.");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mStopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isPlaying){
                    //do nothing
                }else{
                    isPlaying = false;
                    mp.release();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy. You must use before "setDataSource":

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```